# Android Dark Mode/Light Mode - android spinner dropdown popup background color

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a conflicting issue after the Android dark mode introduction into android os, in my app i use following custom style to make the dropdown menu

[image]

in app_text_box_design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryAppBg" />
                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryBorder" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:width="30dp" android:gravity="right">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_white_24" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In the Selector, i use it as below

```
<Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spIam"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_text_box_design"
                    android:padding="10dp" />
```

**Which works fine when in Dark Mode, if define a dark background colour in the Android Dark mode, however, if the user changed to the light mode it conflicts the design, So i am wondering how can we do settings for both modes?**

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to **styles**. You have to declare a particular attribute inside your activity style *to override the default white from MaterialComponents.*

Assuming that your drop down menu is made by menu under res folder you just have to add this **attribute** to the style that you are using:

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorExample</item>
```

Please note that since you have light & dark mode you will have probably two different styles, one called styles.xml and one called styles-night.xml. Make sure to change the colour according to what mode you are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use colors.xml for day/night theme.

```
colors.xml
colors.xml(night)
```

And also please add android:configChanges="uiMode" in your Activity of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```